# @ManyToOne referencedColumnName to UniqueField but not PrimaryKey

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-one, unique-key

I'm found a strange behavior when `@ManyToOne` referenced to not Primary key field.

Part. 1 Reference to not PrimaryKey

Database tables:

```
Sessions
ID number         (pk)
SESSIONID varchar (unique, not null) 

History
ID number         (pk)
SESSIONID varchar (fk to Sessions.SESSIONID)
```

Entityes:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "SESSIONS@ESAD_DB_LINK", schema = "ESAD_OWNER", 
 uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"sessionid"})})
 public class Sessions implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
   @Id
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private BigInteger id;      
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
   @Column(name = "SESSIONID", unique = true)
   private String sessionid;   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "session", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<History> history;
   .........
}

@Entity
  @Table(name = "HISTORY@ESAD_DB_LINK", schema = "ESAD_OWNER")
  public class History implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private BigInteger id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "SESSIONID", referencedColumnName = "SESSIONID")   
  private Sessions session;
  ..........
  }
```

Code:

```
List<History> hsLazy = sessions.getHistory();//Nothing select
for (History hsLazy1 : hsLazy) {  //*           
   System.out.println(hsLazy1.getId());
}
```

*
 ONE SELECT FROM  HISTORY WHERE SESSIONID=?

**Multiple** SELECT FROM SESSIONS WHERE SESSIONID=?, count of SELECT = count of records in child table History

Part.2 Reference to PrimaryKey

Database tables:

```
Sessions
ID number         (pk)
SESSIONID varchar (unique, not null) 

History
ID number         (pk)
SESSIONID number(fk to Sessions.ID)
```

Entityes: Change History to

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "HISTORY@ESAD_DB_LINK", schema = "ESAD_OWNER")
 public class History implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    .......... 
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "SESSIONID", referencedColumnName = "ID",
                                                 nullable=false)   
   private Sessions session;
..........
```

Code:

```
List<History> hsLazy = sessions.getHistory();//Nothing select
for (History hsLazy1 : hsLazy) {  //*           
   System.out.println(hsLazy1.getId());
}
```

* **ONE** SELECT FROM History BY SessionID

Why Hibernate generates a different number of queries when @ManyToOne Reference to not PrimaryKey and Reference to PrimaryKey?
Why so happend?
Is it possible to change behavior when not PK referenced.

P.S. JPA 2.0 Hibernate 4.2.5

Comment: mmmm...What? Can you more clear explain what do you ask about?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases with `@ManyToOne` association you have eager fetching of `Session` object for every `History`. May be, in the second case (Reference to PrimaryKey) Hibernate get `Session` object from a cache, so there is not any additional SQL queries.
My advice is to change fetching to lazy one and fetch `Session` with `join fetch` (or other way) whenever you need it.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SESSIONID", referencedColumnName = "SESSIONID")   
private Sessions session;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate's first level cache is based on the primary key.

If you use the primary key as foreign key then Hibernate can load the object directly from the cache.

If you use a secondary key for the foreign key then Hibernate can't use the first level cache and has to query the database.

Comment: Thank you for response. Will be think how to make redesign of app